# Not able to login by Chrome browser via Selenium Python Code

Tags: google-chrome, selenium-webdriver

I have to open a website where I have to provide the login id and password.
I wrote code in Selenium using Python for webdrivers but I m anot able to login as script is not able to fill the password box where as user name box is filled by script.

below is the code. Same code works on IE and Firefox.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium import webdriver
import selenium.webdriver.chrome.webdriver
from selenium.webdriver import Chrome as Browser
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import Select
from selenium.common.exceptions import NoSuchElementException
import unittest, time, re




    class LoginAa(unittest.TestCase):
        def setUp(self):

            self.driver = webdriver.Chrome()
            self.driver.implicitly_wait(30)
            self.base_url = "https://hostname.com"
            self.verificationErrors = []
            self.accept_next_alert = True

        def test_login_aa(self):
            driver = self.driver
            driver.get("https://hostname.com")
            time.sleep(5)
            self.assertEqual("User Login", driver.title)
            #driver.find_element_by_id("IDToken1").clear()
            driver.find_element_by_id("IDToken1").send_keys("abcd")
            time.sleep(5)

            driver.find_element_by_id("IDToken2").clear()
            driver.find_element_by_id("IDToken2").send_keys("qwerty")
            #driver.find_element_by_css_selector("input[type='password']").click()
```

Comment: "is not able to fill the password". How exactly? Any exceptions?

Comment: no not any exception. while it filled the user name abcd it wont come out got stuck in username box. iS there any way that from username box the goes to password box.